# My brain froze trying to solve this

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, pattern

[image: link to riddle]

Try to figure out the missing numbers!

Comment: Hey, welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! May you please provide a source from where you got this puzzle? I hope you stay with the site :D

Comment: No source sadly

Comment: @İkbalTuncer If there is no source and it is not your puzzle, it will be closed.

Comment: @İkbalTuncer if you forgot the source, kindly just edit the question to mention that it's not yours but you forgot where you found it, otherwise the question might be closed.